# App Engine: Error: [Errno 35] Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: google-app-engine, sockets, blocking, urlfetch

My AppEngine application uses urlfetch to hit a web server that I have running on a computer under my desk.  Occasionally, the call fails with the following error, which I'm hoping you can help me with:

Error: [Errno 35] Resource temporarily unavailable

Herewith, the specifics.

The call to urlfetch runs inside a task and is:

```
r = urlfetch.fetch( URL,
                    payload = urllib.urlencode( { selector: ','.join(records),
                                                  'reason': explain_request,
                                                } ),
                    method = urlfetch.POST,
                    deadline = 600,
                  )
```

Some observations:

- The calls generally seem to fail when the list of records is long (e.g. 100 KBytes after the "join") and succeed when the list is short.  (N.B.: I am not near to exceeding the size limit on a urlfetch request, which is 10 MB according to [this page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview#Quotas_and_Limits).)
- I have only tried this in the GAE development environment, never deployed on GAE itself.
- When I run the server on the same computer as my GAE development environment, the urlfetch calls always succeed.

As far as the server on the computer under my desk:

- It is not responding slowly.  It takes under a second, or maybe just over a second to compute its response.  It's as if GAE does not wait for the response.
- It is connected to the GAE development environment computer via the Internet as a whole (i.e. not an intranet)
- I implemented it the first time using Python's SimpleHTTPServer.
- I implemented it the second time using CherryPy.  The only changes I made to CherryPy's default config were setting the port and setting server.socket_host to '0.0.0.0'.

Based on what I've read on the web about blocking and non-blocking servers, the next thing I would try is implementing the server using an explicitly asynchronous server like Tornado.

But blocking and nonblocking were new concepts to me as of yesterday, so I'm hoping that someone with a true understanding can point me to a more directed attack on this problem.

Thank you.

---

Added 28 May 2013: Well, I never did figure out the problem, or a workaround, but I offer two more clues, in case someone tackles it in the future: (1) It did not appear when deployed to GAE, (2) the problem seemed to have more to do with the size of the POST parameter than with the response of the server-under-the-desk.